# Getting Cell Colors

Tags: html, excel

I have this html code here that will display an Excel file, it has buttons for each page inside the excel file and its purpose is to represent the file that is passed to it. However, it does not copy the cell color over to the cells that represent it. I need to also copy over the cell colors for each cell onto the html representation. Is there any way to do this with this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Excel Preview</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="excelFileInput" accept=".xlsx, .xls" />
  <div id="buttons"></div>
  <div id="preview"></div>

  <script>
    let workbook; // Declare workbook variable

    document.getElementById('excelFileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect);

    function handleFileSelect(event) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        const data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
        workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });
        const sheetNames = workbook.SheetNames;

        // Create buttons for each sheet
        let buttonsHtml = '';
        sheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName, index) {
          buttonsHtml += '<button onclick="displaySheet(' + index + ')">' + sheetName + '</button>';
        });
        document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML = buttonsHtml;

        // Display the first sheet by default
        displaySheet(0);
      };

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }

    function displaySheet(sheetIndex) {
      const sheetNames = workbook.SheetNames;
      const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetNames[sheetIndex]];
      const htmlTable = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(worksheet);

      // Wrap each cell content with <td> element
      const modifiedTable = htmlTable.replace(/<td([^>]*)>/g, '<td class="excel-cell"$1>');

      // Get cell styles from the worksheet
      const cellStyles = worksheet['!cells'];

      // Create a CSS rule for each cell style
      let cssStyles = '';
      for (const cellAddress in cellStyles) {
        const cellStyle = cellStyles[cellAddress];
        if (cellStyle && cellStyle.s && cellStyle.s.fgColor) {
          const fillColor = cellStyle.s.fgColor.rgb.slice(2);
          cssStyles += `td.excel-cell[style*="${cellAddress}"] { background-color: #${fillColor} !important; }`;
        }
      }

      // Create a style element and append the CSS rules
      const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
      styleElement.innerHTML = cssStyles;

      // Append the style element to the document head
      document.head.appendChild(styleElement);

      document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = modifiedTable;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Goolge - Nothing relating to this